# No octop map after point subsample?

Tags: moveit, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I set point_subsample in sensors_rgbd.yaml to a value != the default 1, e.g. 0.5, my planning scene no longer contains a octomap. What can I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65128/no-octop-map-after-point-subsample?/) by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2756 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved the problem by looking into the code:

point_subsample only takes **integer** values.

Setting e.g. `point_subsample: 5` works

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1